# How to not close a form when user presses enter key inside a text box

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, devexpress

Having a [`TextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox) control ([DevExpress `TextEdit`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit) to be precise) inside a WinForms form, I do *not* want the form to close when the user presses the enter key, if the focus is inside the text box.

I thought

```
filterTextBox.KeyDown += 
    (sender, e) => 
        e.Handled = e.KeyCode == Keys.Return || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter;
```

would be sufficient, but it seems to be ignored and the form still closes.

**My question is:**

How to intentionally ignore the enter inside a single line text box control so that the form stays open?

**Solution**

[The solution of Botz3000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10879046/107625) worked for me:

```
filterTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += 
    (sender, e) => 
        e.IsInputKey = e.KeyCode == Keys.Return || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter;
filterTextBox.KeyDown += 
    (sender, e) => 
        e.Handled = e.KeyCode == Keys.Return || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Update***: Try handling the [`PreviewKeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown.aspx) event, too. The MSDN documentation explains it pretty well in the Remarks section. By setting [`IsInputKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.isinputkey.aspx) to true, you can override the default behavior so that your TextBox can handle the key. You'll need to do this in `PreviewKeyDown` and then handle the key as you already do in `KeyDown`.

EDIT: Not working: Previously suggested [`EnterMoveNextControl`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EnterMoveNextControltopic) property

Comment: @UweKeim I updated my answer. Looks like you also need to handle `PreviewKeyDown` so that the enter keypress won't get ignored by the TextBox.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your guys solution, on regular `RichTextBox` handling `PreviewKeyDown` has been good enough.

```
private void rtbNote_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsInputKey = e.KeyCode == Keys.Return || e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without trying it myself, I think I would simply set a boolean in the `KeyDown` of the textbox, then in the Form closing, check for that Boolean and cancel the form closure if it is set (and then reset the boolean).